# Ng-template tag doesn't accept *ngIf directive

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7, but not getting a response when writing the below code in my HTML.

```
<ng-template *ngIf="isStatus"> 
   ... line of code...
 </ng-template>
```

Please help me on this, I am not getting what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I didn't get any error in console, but *ngIf is not working in ng-template. this error is solved by using [ngIf] thanks

Comment: Please state the error that you got and the context that you want to apply `ng-template`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using  then use structural directives as below
Replace your code as below :

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="condition">
    ..............
</ng-template>
```

hope this can help you. for more info refer https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ng-template *ngIf="isStatus()" pTemplate="body">

....line of code
<ng-template>
```

use function and return from there true or false. Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it somewhat like this :-

```js
<ng-template [ngIf]="isStatus"> 
   ... line of code...
 </ng-template>
```

But it is not recommended as per angular community ([Angular structural guide)](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#prefer-the-asterisk--syntax)

Other way  is you can wrap it into div or span tag like this :-

```js
 <div *ngIf="hero.sample">
    Section {{hero.sample}} ,
 </div>
```

But the best way to do it is to wrap in `ng-container` :-

```js
<ng-container *ngIf="hero.demo">
    Section {{hero.demo}} ,
 </ng-container>
```

To get more details about Structural Directives you can visit this link :-
[Angular Structural Directive Guide](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)